# If we have a sequence of 1's, why is the partial sum of it equal to a floor function?

Tags: calculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $a_n = 1$

then why is $$A_n = \sum_1^n a_n = 1+ 1+ ... + 1$$

equal to the floor function $x + O(1)$?

I got this from Wikipedia's page regarding the Abel summation formula.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is not very clear (more like not clear at all). Where comes $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, what you are really asking is different from the formula
$$A_n = \sum_1^n a_n = 1+ 1+\dots + 1$$
which you in the [original version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1562160/1) of your post.

You wrote that you have the formula from Wikipedia article on [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) (here is link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Abel%27s_summation_formula&oldid=675918849) at the time of this post.)

We can see there the formulas 
$$A(x)=\sum_{1\le n\le x} a_n.$$
The article also contains the claim that for $a_n=1$ we get $$A(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor.$$
So I assume this is what you are asking about.

The argument why this works is pretty simple. The sum
$$A(x)=\sum_{1\le n\le x} 1$$
simply counts the number of integers $n$ such that $1\le n \le x$. (Since every such integer adds $+1$ to the sum.)

And the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) is precisely the number of such integers. (Floor function is equal to the integer $k$ such that $k\le x < k+1$. Which means that for every positive integer $n\le k$ we have also $n\le x$. But for any integer $n>k$ we have $n>x$. So we are simply counting positive integers which are less than or equal to $k$. The number of such integers is $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$.)